# .NET Core API call returns 400 Bad request after publish

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, dinktopdf

I am using the DinkToPdf library to create pdf files on a .NET Core 2.2 / Angular app.
Testing it on localhost worked with no problems but the published version returns 400 Bad request.
I call the Print() method of the controller with the authorization token and other parameters. 
As i said, while debugging all works alright.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ExpenseController : Controller
{
        private IConverter _converter;
        public ExpenseController(IConverter converter)
        {
            _converter = converter;
        }

        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Print()
        {
            // IMPLEMENTATION

            var pdf = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
            {
                GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
                Objects = { objectSettings }
            };

            var file = _converter.Convert(pdf);
            return File(file, "application/pdf", "Expense Report.pdf");
        }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any log. Very hard to tell for this case. Can you call api with post man ?

Comment: What is your request? Try to enable `stdout` log or `Developer Exception Page` to check the error details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is generated by the crappy library missing a dll. 
The answer is found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502164/include-dll-and-other-file-during-publishing-in-visual-studio/51858460)
I've copied the libwkhtmltox.dll and libwkhtmltox.so in the root project and set the CopyToOutputDirectory property to 'Copy Always'.